# Trying to locate and delete string in listbox in Python tktinter

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, listbox

Hi I am trying to see if text is in my listbox and then have it deleted but for some reason i get the error

```
return self.tk.call(self._w, 'cget', '-' + key)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
listboxz = Listbox(root,height=40,width=150,bg='pink')
listboxz.pack(side=tk.LEFT,fill='both',expand=True)

listboxz.insert(END, 'hi','bye','see')

if 'bye' in listboxz:
    listboxx.delete()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `listboxx.delete()`.What's the `listboxx`?Did You defined it in another place?

Comment: Meant to be listboxz.delete sorry

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listboxz.get(0, 'end')` to get the list of items:

```
items = listboxz.get(0, 'end')
```

then use `items.index()` to find the item you want to delete:

```
i = items.index('bye')
listboxz.delete(i)
```

If the item cannot be found, `ValueError` will be raised, so better use `try / except`:

```
try:
    items = listboxz.get(0, 'end')
    i = items.index('bye')
    listboxz.delete(i)
except ValueError:
    # item not found, do nothing
    pass
```

Comment: That’s seems like a really good answer I’ll try it out Thankyou very much